# Adding comment to a column of a view in oracle

Tags: oracle, view, comments

Clearly it is possible to add a comment to describe a view, but is it possible to add a comment to describe an individual column of a view in oracle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see [comment on column](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4009.htm)

> Use the COMMENT statement to add a comment about a table, **view**,
>   materialized view, or **column** into the data dictionary.

example

```
create table tst_delete (col1 int); 

create view v_tst_delete as select * from tst_delete;
```

check in SQLPlus

```
SQL> comment on column v_tst_delete.col1 is 'is my view column comment';

Comment added
SQL> desc v_tst_delete
Name Type    Nullable Default Comments                  
---- ------- -------- ------- ------------------------- 
COL1 INTEGER Y                is my view column comment 

SQL>
```

Comment: When I follow the above the above desc only produces the titles Name,Null Type. No comments. However I can see this works by viewing table in SQL Developer. Any ideas why?

Comment: `desc` command is not an SQL statement, but just client side command, which is obviously implemented differently in SQL*Plus and SQL Developer, that's why column `Default` and `Comments` are not present in SQL Developer.